# Como desplazar una submatriz en matlab?

Tags: matlab

Tengo una matriz de 2x2, la cual la quiero insertar mas tarde en una 3x3. Para ello, me gustaría poder desplazar dicha matriz de la siguiente forma:

```
matrix=[1 2 0;
        3 4 0;
        0 0 0];

%resultado deseado
matrix_2=[0 0 0;
          0 1 2;
          0 3 4];`
```

¿Como puedo lograr esta hazaña?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar la función `circshift()` para desplazar los elementos de la matriz una fila a hacia abajo y una columna hacia la derecha:

```
matrix = [1 2 0; 3 4 0; 0 0 0];
matrix2 = circshift(matrix, [0,1]); // desplazando columna a la derecha
matrix2 = circshift(matrix2, [1,0]); // desplazando fila hacia abajo
```

Valor de Matrix2:

```
 0     0     0
 0     1     2
 0     3     4
```